# Cannot SSH to github

Tags: permissions, ssh, github

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday; when i ssh to github, rather than being prompted for a password, it just stalls. The command i entered was:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

After entering, the cursor blinks but nothing comes up. I've tried using the key on my friend's laptop; he gets a permission denied error message, meaning there is different behavior on different machines.
I have a github account with my ssh key included. I was actually able to get my account to work freely on a separate machine, but alas i've had no luck on my personal computer.
For reference, I'm running a Lenovo Ideapad 530s.

UPDATE:
I was able to ssh to github on a different terminal, which is running scientific linux. Thus i am inclined to believe that the problem is related directly to my machine. As i mentioned, i just installed Ubuntu and thus am unsure how my device might be configured improperly.

Comment: `ssh` has the `-v` option. See `man ssh`, and do `ssh -v -T git@github.com`. From the `man` page: `-v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.`

Comment: If you've set up key-based authentication, then you won't necessarily be asked for a pass**phrase** (either because the key doesn't have one, or because it's provided by a running agent). In that case, the fact that you just see a blinking cursor doesn't necessarily indicate a problem - since `-T` tells ssh not to allocate a pseudo-terminal

Comment: So the problem isn't necessarily that i'm not being asked for a passphrase, but rather the terminal window is stalling; meaning i am unable to work freely without using a "cntrl + c" command.

Comment: After using the command suggested by Waltinator, i was able to see that my connection to github is fine, yet my problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup an account on Github and then you can access remote repositories. Github does not provide shell access so you cannot ssh to a git account at github.com.

Use the following link to setup your account and get started with github https://help.github.com/en#dotcom

All of the steps can be found under **Setup**

Comment: I have a github account with my ssh key included. I was actually able to get my account to work freely on a separate machine, but alas i've had no luck on my personal computer.

Comment: @seeminglyhuman Does the new computer have the SSH key that the separate machine had? Does your personal machine have ```git``` installed?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Git is updated to the most recent version as well.

Comment: You may want to check ```git config --list`` on both machines to see what the differences might be (if any)